# List concatenation not working in scala

Tags: scala, list, scala-collections

I am trying to concatenate scala list in loop using below code.

```
var names: List[String] = Nil
val cluster_id = List("149095311_0", "149095311_1")
for (id <- cluster_id) {
  val influencers_name = searchIndex(s"id : $id", "id", "influencers", searcher)
  println("In Loop " + influencers_name)
  names :::= influencers_name
}
for(n <- names) println("List element -> " + n)
```

But when I iterate over final list it give me individual list's instead of individual elements of concatenated List.

Below is the O/P of above code:

```
In Loop List(kroger 10TV DispatchAlerts)
In Loop List(kroger seanhannity SenTedCruz)
List element -> kroger seanhannity SenTedCruz 
List element -> kroger 10TV DispatchAlerts
```

Comment: You create a new list names that's why the List element loop prints each element separately, are u trying to combine each element of the lit into a string ?

Comment: Your ::: functionality is doing what's it's supposed to do i.e concatenating into a new list

Comment: I have to create a list by combining list return from function in the loop.

Comment: it's weird that the first 2 lines of the console output print a `List` but the next 2 lines are not printing any `List`, instead it looks like if it was a `String` of values separated by a space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't very functional in that you are mutating variables. The following is more elegant:

```
def searchIndex(s: String): List[String] = {
  if (s == "149095311_0") List("kroger 10TV DispatchAlerts")
  else List("kroger seanhannity SenTedCruz")
}

val cluster_id = List("149095311_0", "149095311_1")

val names = cluster_id.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
  (acc, id) => acc ++ searchIndex(id)
}

for(n <- names) println("List element -> " + n)
```

Where '++' is used to concatenate the elements of two lists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in searchIndex method that is retreiving a List[String] with a single String that contain all the values separated by a space, fix that method to make sure that it retrieves a List with one elemente per value.

To check if this is right try this, this is just a workaround, you should fix searchIndex

```
var names: List[String] = Nil
val cluster_id = List("149095311_0", "149095311_1")
for (id <- cluster_id) {
  val influencers_name = searchIndex(s"id : $id", "id", "influencers", searcher).flatMap(_.split(' '))
  ("In Loop " + influencers_name)
  names = influencers_name ::: names
}
for(n <- names) println("List element -> " + n)
```

Comment: Return type of searchIndex is List[String], I ahve concatenated List using :::, but it doesn't give me expected O/P.

Comment: In searchIndex List is created using below Code:    var result : List [String] = List()
    for (...) { 
      val value : String = ..
      result = value :: result
    }

Comment: Thanks Mikel for your response. Yes update works for me

Answer (score 0):

The reason is,
When you do names ::: List("anything") -> it does not add anything to names.
Instead, it creates a new collection.
For example,

```
scala> var names: List[String] = Nil
names: List[String] = List()

scala> names ::: List("mahesh")
res0: List[String] = List(mahesh)

You can achive that

scala> names ::: List("chand")
res1: List[String] = List(chand)

scala> res0 ::: List("chand")
res2: List[String] = List(mahesh, chand)
```

When I added "Mahesh" to it, it has created new collection naming res0.
When I added again different string, here "chand" it has created another collection. But when I added "chand" to the created collection, it has concatenated to correct collection,

You can achive What you want to do,

```
scala> for(i <- List("a" ,"b" )){
     | names = i :: names } 

scala> names
res11: List[String] = List(b, a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am concatenating to List using   :::= operator ( names :::= influencers_name). I can see all elements in final List, but they are not returned as single element.

Comment: No, facing same issue.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post whatever changes you made to your method so that it would be easy for others to catch the issue.